# Can I pass partial file path in the variable and access in groovy grails?

Tags: groovy

How Can I pass partial file path in the variable and access in groovy grails?

For-Example-

```
String path = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
File siteFile = new File("${path}/webapps/ROOT/sitemap.xml")
```

Please provide the solution so that I can Implement in my project.

Comment: what is the problem? your code is correct..

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the file using a `Relative Path`. Just Right click the file that you want to get and then select `Copy Relative Path` then use that to get the file.

```
File siteFile = new File("grails-app/assets/images/grails.svg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
String path = System.getProperty( "catalina.base" )
File siteFile = new File("${path}/webapps/ROOT/sitemap.xml")
```